# Video recording doesn't stop even after max duration for it finishes in android xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, video-capture

I want to enable users to record a video for duration up to a max of 2 minutes in my app.
I do provide the max duration for the video recording intent in my code but the recorder doesn't stop after that time. What do i need to do for it ?

Here's the code for recording the video using intent.

```
private void TakeAVideo()
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionVideoCapture);

            RecorderFile._file = new File(RecorderFile._dir, String.Format("vm_movie_{0}.mp4", Guid.NewGuid()));

            if (IsFrontCameraAvailable) {
                intent.PutExtra ("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);
            } else {
                intent.PutExtra ("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 0);
            }
            intent.PutExtra (MediaStore.ExtraDurationLimit, 120000);
            intent.PutExtra (MediaStore.ExtraVideoQuality, 0);
            intent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, Uri.FromFile(RecorderFile._file));

            StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I Figured it out. Basically when we use an `intent` to capture a video we should pass No of Seconds for setting up maximum duration and when we record using `MediaRecorder` then we should set the max duration in milliseconds.

for setting max duration using `intent`

`intent.PutExtra (MediaStore.ExtraDurationLimit, yourDurationInSeconds);`

for setting max duration using `MediaRecorder`

`mediaRecorderObject.SetMaximumDuration(youDurationInMilliSeconds);`